# Insert query MySQL does not working although there is no error message or warning

Tags: php, mysql

Since I am a newbie here, I wanna ask about the query. Insert query seems not working properly althought there is no error message appears. 
Here is the code:

```
<?php
include "../../inc/inc.koneksi.php";

$table      = "admins";

$user       = str_replace("'","\'",$_POST['user']);
$pwd        = md5($_POST['pwd1']);
$nama       = str_replace("'","\'",$_POST['nama']);
$level      = $_POST['level'];
$blokir     = $_POST['blokir'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username, password, nama_lengkap, level, blokir
                   FROM $table 
                   WHERE username= '$user'");
$row    = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($row > 0){
    $input  = "UPDATE $table SET password       ='$pwd',
                                nama_lengkap    ='$nama',
                                level   ='$level',
                                blokir  ='$blokir',
                                lastupdate  = now()
                    WHERE username= '$user'";

    // if(!mysql_query($input));                                
    if ( mysql_query($input) ) {
        echo "Record updated successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong with the query.";
    }


} else {
    $input = "INSERT INTO $table (username, password, nama_lengkap, level, blokir, create) 
                VALUES ('".$user."', '".$pwd."', '".$nama."', '".$level."', '".$blokir."', now() )";

    //if (!mysql_query($input));
    if ( mysql_query($input) ) {
        echo "New record created successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "Something went wrong with the query.";
    }
}   
echo "<br>".$input."<br/>";
?>
```

Really need your help :)

Comment: Error message does not appear because you don't check for it. See `mysql_error()`. PS: be prepared that in a second it will be dozens of comments about sql injections and stopping using obsolete `mysql` extension in favour of mysqli/PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: user mysql error function to see error like eg. mysql_query($input) or die(mysql_error()); will show you error

Comment: Also, you migth want to escape everything that goes into your sql query with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() should be deprecated in favor of parameterized queries.

Comment: @Craig: prepared queries are slower, so don't be so categorical

Comment: @Craig: I'm sure you wanted to address it to me: if it's a one time query, then you need to send data over network twice rather than once. Not to mention that optimizer when has a complete query has better chance to optimize it according the actual data and statistics.

Comment: @FIA2008 No, no, no. You should not do that, or tell people to do that. As zerkms noted, one should use PDO, parametrized or not. That is what you tell people they might want to do, except the might part.

Comment: Parameterized statements are *tons* easier to read in code, less susceptible to human-error bugs, and if the optimizer can't do the right thing with it that's a serious weakness in MySQL. Is that really true? Wow.  And they also do away with the entire security-weak pattern of concatenating SQL statements together. Honestly, my even stronger preference is to use stored procedures. Bring on the flames.

Comment: @Craig There's no reason to flame such an obvious statement. However, I suggest that you expand your answer to show HOW to do the things you suggest the OP does, otherwise you're just spouting cargo cult programming.

Comment: @zerkms  Yes, meant to address that to you.  ;-)

Comment: @ChrisBaker I was half-jokingly saying "Bring on the flames" with regard to my stored procedure preference...  ;-)

Comment: @Craig, prove what? Yes, `mysql_real_escape_string` should be deprecated. But looking at his code, he' not working with PDO, so explaining PDO is a little too much off topic don't you think? Also, please address to right person ;)

Comment: @FIA2008  hahaha...  ;-)  *maybe* bringing up PDO is a little too much. But on the other hand, he's using a deprecated API and will be pushed over that ledge eventually, anyway. Might as well hold his nose and jump!

Comment: @Craig: it's not a mysql issue. Every DBMS engine must find a balance between caching not optimal plans (since you don't have parameters yet) or just not cache plans at all (and evaluate them every time). Btw, prepared statements have the same performance penalties, it does not matter where you invoke a parameterized query from.

Comment: @zerkms Well, sure, but most databases I've worked with a lot (SQL Server, Oracle, SQL Anywwhere, PostgreSQL) seem to do a reasonable job of compiling and caching a query plan that uses table and index statistics efficiently enough to perform pretty well. And I've really sort of come around to the 80/20 perspective in terms of performance. At least we're not talking about using an ORM (shudder).

Comment: @zerkms The performance concerns related to prepared statements are negligible, and sort of a moot point considering the `mysql_` API is going away. One could use mysqli or PDO and keep concatenating, but the minimal potential performance gain isn't enough to justify all the extra code (and function calls) used to manually escape everything. Especially for insert queries as the OP is asking about, there is not going to be any caching involved.

Comment: @Chris Baker: native prepared statements == at least one more network interaction. So your one off queries automatically become at least 1 network latency (roundtrip actually) slower. When you understand what you do and how it all works - there is nothing terribly bad in using tools how you want to, not how community thinks everyone should.

Comment: @zerkms not sure what the last bit of your comment was implying, but I'm very well aware of how it works. The "network latency" when your SQL server is localhost (most use cases) is negligible, and even on a remote box the security benefits and code legibility outweigh the performance concerns. If you show me a box where prepared statements are having a measurable affect on performance, I'll show you a box that needs to have the settings adjusted or a hardware upgrade. Or you should have a server farm because your load is too high. You can be a rebel if you want, not sure what your point is.

Comment: @Chris Baker: "Or you should have a server farm because your load is too high" --- you're confusing load with latency. They are different things. But anyway, I expressed my point clearly: prepared statements is not panacea and one is free not to use them and still write nice and secure code. If you think it's not possible - okay. "when your SQL server is localhost" --- in any project bigger than a home page RDBMS server is dedicated to a web/application server due to performance optimization reasons. Not sure how a person aware of performance would say "most use cases".

Comment: @zerkms This pedantry is helpful to the OP how? You're arguing against a straw man -- no one here is speaking in absolutes. In the case at hand, the OP, there's no reason not to suggest prepared statements without an in-depth analysis of whether they are the best choice in every situation, ever. Anyway.... Fikri Gustiawan just got an earful. Hope it wasn't confusing and misleading. Look at the code in the OP. The SQL server is localhost. Calm down.

Comment: @Chris Baker: my point from the very beginning was: don't be categorical but learn/measure instead. It is more important to teach a newbie "WHY prepared statements" instead of dummy "always use prepared statements" mantra. Since absolutes are more harm for newbies than good.

Comment: @zerkms That's an awful lot to throw at a newbie. Absolutes are useful for new programmers because many never advance beyond "tinkering", and the absolutes cover those bases fine. Better than `mysql_query`. I also wonder if now is a good time to remind you that PHP uses emulated prepares by default, so the hypothetical deal-breaking extra round trip isn't actually happening unless it is explicitly enabled. When doing so, odds are you've advanced to the point where distinctions in the absolutes you learned before are important and make themselves known. Anyway, good night.

Comment: @ChrisBaker "if now is a good time to remind" --- I'm always keep that in mind, that's why I explicitly mentioned "*native prepared statements*" :-) Anyway, I have a different point of view on how it's more efficient to teach newbies - I don't think absolutes are good. Anyway, it doesn't matter, have a good day :-)

Comment: Getting back to the topic, you have three queries here, but you only need one. See INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Comment: @zerkms Wow, guys. Look, using prepared statements lends itself naturally to more legible (consequently less buggy) code. The concatenation thing was fine in 1992 when the tools across the board were less mature. Correctness trumps performance *unless* performance proves to be a real issue. What Chris Baker and I are both saying (pardon me for assuming, Chris) is that you really should make it correct, *then* if you have performance issues look to optimize where it matters. And chances are *very* good that the optimization still won't have to include buggy, insecure concatenated SQL.

Comment: @Craig: "to include buggy, insecure concatenated SQL" --- there is no problem to implement a secure and correct sql without prepared statements. Placeholders are really overvalued, *mostly* by people who don't understand that every injection (sql or xss or shell) is just an AST mutation. After you realize that - there is no difference between how you do that.

Comment: @zerkms long overblown chunks of concatenated SQL are friggin' HARD TO READ, which makes them prone to bugs. You're mixing multiple languages every time you do that, and the fact is that humans screw that stuff up on a regular basis. It's just the way it is. SQL templates with placeholders are simply easier to read. On top of that, the framework doing the proper cleanup and escaping on your arguments can absolutely be taken for granted, instead of having to rely on error-prone humans again to call a function on EVERY substitution to ensure it's clean and free from SQL injection possibilities.

Comment: @Craig: I have a personal opinion that is based on 10+ years of software development. It's unlikely it is to change it after a 10 minutes conversation. I see your point, I have different one though.

Comment: @Craig: "But if you really want to try that hard to make your PHP code look exactly like Visual Basic" --- no reason to do it like that. There is a balance. If it's a whitelisted constant enum value of 3 integer variables - you can safely use it like `SELECT foo FROM table WHERE status = $status_id` and it will not be less readable **at all**. Like **AT ALL**

Comment: @zerkms I was swamped a while ago, and honestly don't want to have an argument. I deleted the comment you (partially) quoted from before I saw your response, but apparently not quick enough for you to see it first. The named variable string substitution in PHP is not quite like VB string concatenation (and I know PHP has always been efficient at string concatenation because of its mutable strings). So I deleted that comment. However; none of this addresses the reality that humans make really dumb mistakes as a matter of course, and this approach is still highly susceptible to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You really should look into using [prepared statements/parameterized SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16095350/618649) instead of schlocking your SQL together this way.

SQL Injection really is a serious security problem with the way you have this structured.

Why are you concatenating the table name into the SQL when it is just a string constant?

**EDIT**: The following short snippet was included in the answer (one of mine from a ways back) I referenced in the hyperlink above. I find this pattern tons easier to read than concatenated SQL (which is *so* 1991 Visual Basic, by the way). You can also cache the prepared statement if it is used often enough to matter.

```php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($username, $password));
```

I am also a big fan, personally, of using database stored procedures, but won't go into that in the interest of space and time here. One bonus of a stored procedure in the context that we're dealing with here is that they're easy to test completely independent of your PHP code. Then you just have to pass them the right parameters when you make the call from PHP and everything will work the way it did in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` is deprecated and should not be used for new code. Use PDO for database access, and get the error message from the database connection/statement handler.

The example below shows you how to set up PDO, how to do a prepared statement, and how to get the error message if there is one. Take note that we're not concatenating the values into strings, we're passing them as named parameters. PDO will take care of sanitizing and escaping when you do it this way. I also removed the variable for the table name -- just type it into the query.

```
// This is how to establish a PDO connection
$host="[replace me]"; // Host name
$username="[replace me]"; // username
$password="[replace me]"; // password
$db_name="[replace me]"; // Database name

/*
  you do this once, then pass $pdo into class constructors or as a function argument
  when db access is needed
  do not use the global keyword. don't do it.
*/
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name, $username, $password);


/*
  before you do your query, you should validate the input. Make sure all the 
 fields exist, and have valid data. You should not assume they're there and valid,
 even if you validated the form with javascript. This is one of many ways to do it.
*/

$errors = array();
foreach (
    array(
        'username',
        'pwd1',
        'nama',
        'level',
        'blokir'
    ) as $field
){
    if (
        array_key_exists($field, $_POST) === false || 
        strlen(trim($_POST[$field])) < 1
    ){
        $errors[] = 'Missing required field: '.$field;
    }
}

// only do the query if you have all the values!
$result = false;
if (count($errors) === 0) {
    // make a prepared statement
    $pdoStatement= $pdo->prepare('
        INSERT INTO admins (
            username,
            password,
            nama_lengkap,
            level,
            blokir,
            create
        ) VALUES (
            :username,
            :password,
            :nama_lengkap,
            :level,
            :blokir,
            NOW()
        )
    ');
    $result = $pdoStatement->execute(array(
       'username'=>$_POST['user'],
       'password'=>$_POST['pwd1'],
       'nama_lengkap'=>$_POST['nama'],
       'level'=>$_POST['level'],
       'blokir'=>$_POST['blokir']
    ));
    if (!$result) $errors = $pdoStatement->errorInfo();
}
if (!$result){
    // do something better with the error messages!
    echo 'There were errors: <ul><li>'.implode('</li><li>', $errors).'</li></ul>';
}
```

**Documentation**

- `PDO` - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- `PDO::prepare` - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
- `PDOStatement` - http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php
- `PDOStatement::execute` - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
- `PDOStatement::errorInfo` - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php

Comment: Kudos for including a full example like I failed to do... I was surprised to see the comments on the OP's post went on so long. I threw in a parting thought there.